# Javascript controls order form's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am currently creating an order form. However, I have been stuck at the value obtaining.
It is a product order form, I want to display price and calculate the amount by users' choosing.

For example, I got a product quantity drop down list, so when the user chooses one product, the price div will display one value, if the user chooses 0, the price div will display $0. Where is the problem?

```
var productValue = document.getElementById("e_Product");
var productQuantity = document.getElementById("e_Quantity");
var stringValue = productValue.options[productValue.selectedIndex].text;

if (stringValue == "Product Name" && productQuantity == 1) 
{
    var singleValue = "$800.00";
    $('#e_Price').val(singleValue);
}
else
{
    var singleValue1 = "$0.00";
    $('#e_Price').val(singleValue1);
}
```

Also, in a form, how to disable the edit function to the input fields? I found when I obtain the value for those product, the user still can type whatever they want in the fields.

For displaying values in input fields, I feel that i can only use val() to output the value, so everytime I need to set a new variable to hold the value, but for the order form, I want to add a calculation function at the end. Like the user chooses the product, product quantity and the shipping options, I need to get the amount of all those fees.

Sorry about the expression, a little bit mess, several questions are put together, kinda have no idea what I am doing.

Thank you guys very much in advance.

Comment: And where do you attach the event handler?

Comment: Better yet, can you also show us your html, as well as the rest of your js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use global variable

```
var singleValue = "$0.00";
if (stringValue == "Product Name" && productQuantity == 1) 
{
  singleValue = "$800.00";
$('#e_Price').val(singleValue);
}
else
{
 $('#e_Price').val(singleValue);
}
```

For disable textbox (total amount field)

```
$('#id').attr('disabled',true);
```

or

```
$('#id').attr('disabled','disabled');
```